# Try/Catch, catch if filter returns nothing

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I want to output a message if `$ADUser` returns nothing but somehow it doesn't hit the catch block:

```
$Paths = Get-childitem '\\sto-fs-02\Users\Pictures' |Select Fullname
Foreach ($Path in $paths){
$ADName = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($path)
$TrimmedADName = $ADName.Replace('.',' ')
Try
{

    $ADUser = Get-ADUser {name -like $TrimmedADName}
    $ADUser.name
}
catch
{
write-host "$trimmedADName can't be found, fix filename"

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use a `try-catch` block here. Just check whether `$ADUser` is not null:

```
$Paths = Get-childitem '\\sto-fs-02\Users\Pictures' |Select Fullname
Foreach ($Path in $paths) {
    $ADName = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($path)
    $TrimmedADName = $ADName.Replace('.',' ')

    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -filter {name -like $TrimmedADName}

    if ($ADUser)
    {
        $ADUser.name
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "$trimmedADName can't be found, fix filename"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - A good trick if you do want to use try/catch in certain situations and aren't sure if it is going to throw a terminating error and fall to the catch, you can check for a value in a variable and create your own terminating errors. So you could do something like this:

```
$Paths = Get-childitem '\\sto-fs-02\Users\Pictures' |Select Fullname
Foreach ($Path in $paths) {
    $ADName = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($path)
    $TrimmedADName = $ADName.Replace('.',' ')
try{
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -filter {name -like $TrimmedADName}

    if (!$ADUser) {
         throw
    }
} catch {
    write-host "$trimmedADName can't be found, fix filename"
}
```